# Chosing the right type of convolution code for a M-QAM transmitter

Tags: channelcoding

Coming from my previous question [(link to this here)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85564/selecting-convolutional-code-for-a-m-qam-transmitter/85572#85572). Given the following transmitter design,

[image]

with these parameters,

1. bit rate of 55 Mbps
2. maximum bandwidth of 17 MHz
3. code rate : 1/2
4. minimum SNR to design for 10dB
5. maximum SNR to design for 80dB
6. maximum data block length 256
7. decoding with Viterbi

How can I determine which convolutional code structure I should be using?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140973/discussion-on-question-by-albussimba-chosing-the-right-type-of-convolution-code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So work off what you've got:

0. **convolutional code**: Important design constraint. (The rest of the application description really doesn't say this is necessarily a good use case for a convolutional encoder.)
1. **bit rate of 55 Mbps**: This means you get $55/\log_2(M)$ symbols per second
2. **maximum bandwidth of 17 MHz**: You get a bandwidth factor of $$\frac{\frac{55\cdot 10^6}{\log_2 M}}{17\cdot 10⁶}= \frac{55}{17\cdot \log_2 M};$$ for $M=32$ in 32-QAM as in your picture, that amounts to 0.64; this allows us to design a pulse shaping filter, but assuming we normalize the filter's energy, it has no effect on the channel code design. 
   Knowing the bandwidth however is important to find bounds.
3. **code rate $r=1/2$**: setting both the code type and the rate is quite an unusual constraint for a system design these days! But anyways, OK, that means that our $E_b/N_0=\text{SNR}/(2\cdot \log_2M)$, as there's two code bits that we make out of each info bit, and there's $\log_2 M$ bits that share the energy of one symbol. (Remark: Rate 1/2 seems very low for good SNRs)
4. **minimum SNR to design for 10 dB**: This will be the "hard" end of our operational range. We need to design such that our application still works with the errors we can't avoid at that SNR.
5. **maximum SNR to design for 80 dB**: This is not as important, but will allows to derive things like whether it makes sense to send the systematic part first followed by a checksum to avoid all decoding in order to save energy in case there's nothing to correct anyway.
6. **maximum data block length 256 bits**: That means that after $T=256$ info bits, we terminate our code. This limits the complexity of our decoder (because a constraint length $L$ larger than this makes no sense, anyway, and because we get to backtrack latest after 256 bits), and effectively turns our convolutional code a block code (and not a very long at that).
7. **decoding with Viterbi**: this means we're designing for a decoder that achieves MAP performance – we don't have to design for the specifics of any particular decoder. However, it also means that our space requirement is $O(T\cdot 2^L)$.

Missing steps from here:

## 1. Define Design Targets

So, next step would always be finding out how good "good enough" is. Your application calls for a frame or bit error rate – getting better is nice, but if we buy it with e.g. exponentially exploding power consumption, might not be the way to go.

## 2. Check Design Achievability

Though a very short (as in: 256 bits) rate 1/2 convolutional code will be very far away from Shannon Channel capacity (because that assumes infinite length, and it can be shown that finite blocklengths inherently reduce capacity bounds, no matter how well we design), it's worth checking whether the desired rates is Shannon-achievable at the worst SNR, 10 dB = 10¹:

\begin{align}
R &\overset?\le C = B \cdot \log_2(1+\text{SNR})\\
\frac RB &\overset?\le \log_2(1+\text{SNR})\\[1em]
 \frac{55\cdot 10^6}{17\cdot 10^6}  &\overset?\le  \log_2(1+10^{1})\\
 \frac{5.5}{1.7}  &\overset?\le  \log_2(11)\\
3.26 &\overset?\le 3.46
\end{align}

That's actually pretty close! So your code needs to be very close to optimal.

It's hence necessary to check whether achieving the required capacity of 55/17 = 3.26 bits per channel usage is possible at all in the *finite block-length regime*[1]. If theory says our code is impossible, we can stop designing right here, and write a nice email that we can't do the undoable, but are willing to meet with the application team to help them redefine their requirements. This might just mean you just say "hey, I don't care about capacity, let's deal with

Now, two things: it's very unlikely that you hit a sweet spot when you defined the rate to be 1/2; you'll probably not find a code that allows you to achieve rate. Thus, you can basically take this number and go back to the designer who said that this needs to be 1/2 and tell them that you'll probably end up not finding a code, and that they need to relax that constraint. Think about it: by choosing this rate, you *force* the encoder to spread the energy it has for one info bit to two code bits. Maybe it would be better to go for rate 3/4 and transmit less code bits per second, thereby giving us more energy per info bit? Who knows! All we know is that we have very little wiggle room from a theoretical maximum that might lie who knows at which rate!

Then, this makes it very likely you'll also not want a binary convolutional code that can be decoded with a straightforward Viterbi: You need a large constraint size to get even close to capacity, where you have to be, but with a large constraint size, termination eats up significant energy. So, you'll at the very least will want to use a tailbiting convolutional code, as at least proposed (and I think it made it) for 5G's URLLC (ultra-reliable low latency communication) modes. (Note how 256 bit block lengths are considered a case of "low latency" requirements – this is a short code by modern standards.)
A survey on URLLC codes is found in [2]. A higher-quality publication of short tailbiting convolutional codes (why would you use normal ones?) is in [3].

**However**, let's act as if all was peachy here, and move on.

## 3. Find Constraints on Complexity

OK, we're allowed to go for a Viterbi algorithm. From looking at the trellis, we know that each "column" of the trellis contains all the states the shift register we're feeding our info bits into – because that's all the possible internal states in each time step. For a binary shift register of length $L$, that's $2^L$ states – and knowing we won't be throwing away any ability to correct or any payload bits, we know that we'll  have $T=256$ time steps. So, the memory required to keep all the path metrics is $2^L \cdot 256 \cdot w$ bits, where $w$ is the number of bits we resolve our log-likelihoods with. Quick tabular consideration with three columns: One for the constrain length, one for the number of weights to store, and one assuming 4 bit weights (more bits have diminishing return at a 10 dB AWGN)

$$\begin{array}{c|c|cl} 
 L & 2^{L}\cdot T \,\text{(words)} & 2^{L} \cdot T \cdot 4 \,\text{(bits)}  \\ \hline
0 & 256 & 1024 &\text{not really a convolutional code}\\
1 & 512 & 2048\\
2 & 1024 & 4096\\
3 & 2048 & 8192\\
4 & 4096 & 2^{14}\\
5 & 8192 & 2^{15}\\
6 & 2^{14} & 2^{16}\\
7 & 2^{15} & 2^{17}\\
8 & 2^{16} & 2^{18}& \text{smallest 5G Tailbiting convolutional code, far from $C$}\\
9 & 2^{17} & 2^{19}\\
10 & 2^{18} & 2^{20}\\
11 & 2^{19} & 2^{21} & \text{first URLLC TB-CC to perform potentially close enough at rate 1/2} \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
14 & 2^{22} & 2^{24} & \text{[3, Fig. 5]: at a 256 bit length, the three additional bits constraint length pay}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\text{need more constraint length to compensate for not tail-biting}\\[-0.3em]
&&&\text{which means at this point we're throwing away roughly half}\\[-0.3em]
&&&\text{a constraint length in error-correction information.}\\
21 & 2^{29} & 2^{31} &\text{My wild guess what compensates for not TB'ing}\\[-0.3em]
&&&\text{Note how this is 256 MB of memory for our Viterbi.}\\[-0.3em]
&&&\text{"Slow" does not even start to describe its performance.}\\[-0.3em]
\end{array}$$

For quick reference, here's [3, Fig. 5]: 
[image: Fig. 5. Codeword error rate vs Eb /N0 for (256, 128) TBCCs. The markers denote simulation results, whereas the dashed lines provide the corresponding codes TSBs on the ML block error probability].

Note how for an SNR of 10 dB, and a rate of 1/2 and $M=32$, you get $E_b/N_0 = (10 - 3 - 7)\,\text{dB} = 0\,\text{dB}$. But at $M=16$, you get $1\, \text{dB}$, and thus some frame error rate of roughly 0.1 (and you still get to send 4 bits per channel access, which is enough to get 55 Mb/s out of 17 MHz). Notice the solid black line? That's the sphere packing bound for a rate-1/2 binary code of length 256; it's impossible to get less errors than that on average. Hmpf! Can your application deal with 1/10 of broken frames? Maybe it can, maybe it can't. You'll need to talk to your requirements engineering, so go back to 1.!

## 4. Choosing/Designing the Actual Code

Since we're BER-performance (and not complexity) limited, we'll go for Maximum-distance separable (MDS) codes, as they achieve the Singleton bound. Nice that for once we know in which direction to look[4]!

I'm really no expert in designing convolutional codes; but with just 21 bits of search space (that's 2 million) (and realistically, it's just $\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 21 \end{pmatrix}= 352716$, as both sparse and overly dense polynomials will have undesirable property, but I'm not sure about that, would have to review [4]) and error rates in the order of 10⁻¹, assuming you have a few CPU cores to spare, decoding say 10⁵ random frames with random noise per possible polynomial should be quite doable for a serious design.

## 5. Review

The definition of non-tailbiting convolutional code for a frame length of but 256 was wrong, and so was settling on a rate of 1/2 before defining what the application needs. Even at lengths where tail-biting convolutional codes barely achieve anything akin to useful frame error rates, your (modified for tailbiting) Viterbi isn't that much faster than block soft-decoders.

The following figure is generated from https://pretty-good-codes.org/compare ; Vertically you see the frame error rate (solid) or bit error rate (dashed), horizontally we're talking SNR. 
[image: Code Comparison]
The winner is the "[5G UCI](https://pretty-good-codes.org/polar)" code with a decoder that does successive cancellation list decoding with a (rather large) list of 32 candidates, and an included CRC11. That's not too surprising, for 256 bits length a 32-candidates list decoder with a solid element decoder will perform pretty well, I guess. But it's still not achieving the performance of the (256,128) TB-CC from [3], but that needs to find all closed paths – which are easily more than 32 candidates. So, quite likely, you buy that FER performance with a highly increased decoding complexity (might really be OK, though. Still a short code.)

---

[1] Y. Polyanskiy, H. V. Poor and S. Verdu, "Channel Coding Rate in the Finite Blocklength Regime," in *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory*, vol. 56, no. 5, pp. 2307-2359, May 2010, doi: 10.1109/TIT.2010.2043769. Available [online](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/finite_block.pdf) from the author's  faculty website.

[2] Shirvanimoghaddam, Mahyar, et al. "Short block-length codes for ultra-reliable low latency communications." in *IEEE Communications Magazine* 57.2 (2018): 130-137. Available [online](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09166) as arXiv:1802.09166 [cs.IT])

[3] Gaudio, L., Ninacs, T., Jerkovits, T., & Liva, G. "On the performance of short tail-biting convolutional codes for ultra-reliable communications." in *SCC 2017; 11th International ITG Conference on Systems, Communications and Coding*. VDE, 2017. Available [online](https://elib.dlr.de/111913/1/SCC2017_TB_Codes_v8.pdf) from the authors' institution website.

[4] Smarandache, Roxana, Heide Gluesing-Luerssen, and Joachim Rosenthal. "Constructions of MDS-Convolutional Codes." In *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory* 47.5 (2001): 2045. Available [online](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ersmarand/docs/Construction-MDS.pdf) from the author's faculty website.

Comment: Thank you for putting up with my loose requirements. The post is very informative.